# calculating number of bytes of each row in an image

Tags: opencv

How can we calculate the size of each row in bytes of a 3 channel image. I know it is no. of columns * element size. But I have seen in some books and on internet that sometimes the rows are padded with extra pixels for efficiency. So in those cases the above formula won't work because the number of bytes in this case will increase. Am I right ?? Please explain. Also I was able to find an attribute "step" to find the size of first row in bytes .

I used it as img.step[0] // It Gave no. of bytes in first row

But when I tried to find the size of second row using img.step[1], it gave some garbage value. Please explain what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a step is applied to all rows of an image. The size of all rows will be the same as the size of the first row.

Comment: How is it applied?? Please give an example.

Comment: I mean to say that the same padding is applied to all rows of an image. So if you are working with an image of dimension 62 x 50, 2 bytes will be added at the end of each row to make the padded image 64 x 50.

Comment: yes I know that a row should be a multiple of 4 or 8 but I want to know is there any attribute with the help of which we can directly determine the no. of bytes in a row in c++?

Comment: Here's the documentation for the step size: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat
The index into img.step takes you through the dimensions, not the rows. For a 2D image, img.step[0] should be the number of bytes in a row, and img.step[1] should be the number of bytes in a single element. I'm not sure why you are seeing garbage there.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the field `IplImage.widthStep`

> Size of aligned image row in bytes

**Edit:** You said you are using `OpenCv 2`. Im assuming you are using cv::Mat.

In this case cv::Mat.step should give you the width of the row.

> a distance between successive rows in bytes; includes the gap if any

However I would suggest to use method `cv::Mat::ptr(row)` to accces each row. This will return an `uchar*` to raw row data.

Comment: Sir I am working in Opencv2 with c++ interface. so please tell me a c++ attribute. Thanks.