# QPixmap fromImage gives segment fault on image converted from cv::mat

Tags: qt, opencv, qt5, qpixmap

I simplified the code and it is like this:

```
Mat mat = imread("xxx.jpg"); //Successfully read the image, confirmed by cvShowImage.

if (mat.empty())
{
    qDebug() << "Couldn't load image";
    return;
}

Mat cpy = mat.clone();
cvtColor(mat,cpy,CV_BGR2RGB);
QImage image(cpy.data, cpy.cols, cpy.rows, cpy.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);

try {
    pm = QPixmap::fromImage(image); //crash line
} catch(std::exception const &ex){
    qDebug()<<ex.what();
}
```

however the program just crashed without any debug log.. I've tried many images and the result is same. I tried to find the "stack trace" and it seems give segfault on this..

[image]

Comment: First you do `QImage image(...);` then you do `pm = QPixmap::fromImage(fim);`. What is `fim`? (The reason for the crash?) I warmly suggest to make this as [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If this doesn't solve your problem it will at least help to raise more attention in this community.

Comment: I gues fim holds some unitialized data

Comment: @Scheff Ah sorry sorry. that should be "image" but not "fim" because I copied codes from different functions.

Comment: Sometimes, image lines have to be provided with certain alignment. (seen e.g. in OpenGL) Thus, if you have triples (RGB values), due to the value in `cpy.cols` the resulting number of bytes might be (or might be not) a multiple of 4 where `QImage` might expect the opposite. I just had a look into Qt doc. [QImage::bytesPerLine()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#bytesPerLine) but couldn't find something about this on the first glance. You may dig deeper into this direction. IMHO, it could be an explanation for the seg. fault as you're code is looking "innocent" beside of this.

Comment: Ah. Have a look at Qt doc. of the constructor you used: [QImage::QImage()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-3): _...data must be 32-bit aligned, and each scanline of data in the image must also be 32-bit aligned._ Are you sure that `cv::mat` does provide the data this way?

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for your work. I don't know much about alignment or rgb things, but the conversion code I used (QImage() context to convert cv::mat to QImage) seems widely confirmed as an official way? I googled many solutions and they are just similar like that. So it should be 32-bit aligned I think..

Comment: Found this: [SO: Stride on image using Opencv C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11573107/7478597). It seems that `imread()` aligns scanlines to multiples of 4 as well. You may use [cv::Mat::isContinuous()](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa90cea495029c7d1ee0a41361ccecdf3) to check this.

Comment: I just realized that you use the QImage constructor which gets the bytesPerLine as 4th argument. The OpenCV doc. (I found) doesn't say the actual meaning of `cv::Mat::step` but it seems you're using it right. [SO: calculating number of bytes of each row in an image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24886540/7478597) Hmmm. (No more ideas...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay.. just change the conversion code to

```
QImage image(cpy.data, cpy.cols, cpy.rows, cpy.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
image = image.rgbSwapped();
```

solved it. Actually I don't know why this fixed it. Maybe because I should use COLOR_BGR2RGB rather than CV_BGR2RGB..

Answer (score 3):

Had similar crash in QPixmap.fromImage. Found workaround by resizing image to a size aligned to 4 bytes

```
aligned = cv2.resize(img, (img.shape[1]//4*4, img.shape[0]//4*4), fx=0, fy=0, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(aligned, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
qimage = QImage(rgb.data, rgb.shape[1], rgb.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(qimage)
```